# Cheap alternatives to translucent polycarbonate sheet?

Tags: acrylic

I'm looking for a material to cover an uninsulated wall that is both durable and translucent enough to diffuse sunlight inside.

Polycarbonate sheeting looks like the best material for the job but is expensive and not easy to find. Plexiglass, acrylic etc. also seem expensive for how long it seems to last given some reviews. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Poly carbonate ( eg. Lexan) is substantially stronger than any other plastic sheet goods.  Either you need poly carbonate or you don't, there is no substitute .

Answer (score 1):

I'm rather fond of polycarb corrugated roofing panels. They price out at about $1/sf and are available in transparent-but-distorted charcoal or clear, and translucent white that diffuses as you wish.